# How to create a login application with Visual Basic (using WebHttpRequest)

Tags: c++, vb.net

Hei there, I'm not experienced at all in C++ as I need to start learning year the next year at my university, though, I've been creating a browser based game and I'm looking for someone to transform it into pc app.

Though, I'm wondering how to make that application send a http request via POST to a file on my webserver with the username / pw.

After all the tutotials I've been reading, I concluded that none worth spending my time with, because they all based on own database, and I'm looking for one that connects to a maestro server and requests the data from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to find a friend that would do it in Delphi because I wouldn't want users to download net framework just for this ap.

So the program that would fit most for any apps is Delphi Prism XE (even if it's an addon of Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but you may consider two alternatives to a more pure C++ application.

1. If you already have a working browser game, try to take that same code and put the html/javascript/whatever in a file and give the file a ".hta" extention. It basically opens inside a browser to run your files, but it acts more like an application from the user's viewpoint. (And, as much as I hate Windows, they're pretty fun to create if I may say so).  However, your source code with this option is easily read because it can be renamed to a text file (or html file).
2. You could use Visual C++ (or VB.net, which you have tagged to the question, as well as "Visual" C#) to create an application which mostly consists of a browser view.  It could be a "standalone" application (however would rely completely on the .Net framework - may or may not be what you want) that basically accomplishes the same as the option above, but adds that you can "hide" your files inside your application.

Using the two above alternatives, you could make an application relatively quickly that would load your files, which I assume you have already created.  Note that neither of the above alternatives will work on anything other than Windows OS's.

If the two above alternatives are not what you want, or if you have questions about either one, I'd be glad to attempt to help.